# How can I repeatedly call a function from a views.py in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, python-2.7

How can I repeatedly call a function from a views.py in Django?

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^report/(?P<extension>\d+)/$', views.report),
]
```

views.py

```
def report(request, extension):

    """
        I will do some logic here. I need the extension variable for 
        database purposes.
      EX: 
        my_array = Report.objects.fetching_reports(extension='3')
    """

    return render(request, 'report.html’)
```

If you notice in extension, I passed in 3. The idea is that each extension will have their own data. However, I want them to render on the same html template. I will begin rendering from extension 1, up to 12 then goes back to 1. Let’s say extension 4 is missing, it will be redirected to extension 5.These extension will come from my database.

```
Example:

…/report/1/
…/report/2/
…/report/3/    ## will skip 4 if not available 
…/report/5/
…/report/6/    ## and so on..
```

Each extension will render the same HMTL template. Right now, I can successfully render these reports if I type the URL patter directly to the browser. Is there a way to call report( ) continuously, let’s say every 15 seconds? Or should I have a different approach to this?

Thank you very much for reading.

Answer (score 1):

```
def report(request, extension):

    try:
        my_array = Report.objects.fetching_reports(extension=extension)
    except Report.DoesNotExist:
        my_array = None

    extension +=1

    if my_array = None:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('your_project_name':'your_app_name', kwargs = {'extension':extension}))
    else:
        return render(request, 'report.html', {'extension':extension})
```

that will skip to the next object if 4 doesn't exist, if you wanna skip after 15 seconds you can do a JavaScript redirecting to the next page and using extension var

Comment: Hello, Mauricio. Will give it a try now and update you! thank you so much

Comment: If I don't add a JS for now, how can this be redirected to the next extension?

Comment: That's hard, because Django just send the template to the browser and that's it, no more. The only way is using js. Don't forget accept t it

Comment: Can I do something like this?

def my_report(request, extension):

    ## some logic

    return render(request, 'index.html')


def render(request):

    extensions_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

    for i in extensions_array:

        my_report(extension=i)
        ## can I do somthing like this?
        ## then in my js I can keep calling this route

Comment: the best way and scalable is like @Haken said, just replace {{next}} for what I put in the comment, remember pass the extension var

Answer (score 1):

For each report, pass a `next` url to the template and use javascript to reload.

```
<script>
  function nextReport() { window.location.href = "{{ next }}"; }
  setTimeout(nextReport, 15000);
</script>
```

Comment: maybe you can use {% url  'your_project:your_app' exception %}

Comment: Thank you! I actually have been using the JS redirect function. but I wanted to see if I can do such thing in the backend also.

Comment: No. You cannot do that only in the backend. If you want to avoid the browser refresh, you can use ajax to get the new page content.